# Moving data in one table to another table Based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I need help in figuring out the solution for my problem.

**1. I have a 4 tables**

```
a. CLientdetails
b. ClientAccountDetails
c. ClientExistingData
d. ClientNotExistindata.
```

Clinet details contains data related to the name of the client, startingdate, endingDate

ClientAccountDetails contains data related to specific client(ie multiple accounts asscoiated with his name, status of the account, money)

using SSIS package i import data from Excel sheet(data related to excel sheet is of ClientAccountDetails) into a different table called IMPORTClientDetails.

when all the data gets imported to the table using ssis package. i would write some query to move that into the ClientAccountDetails table based on the Name of the Client.

**2. My question is**

If the Client name from IMPORTClientDetails doesnot exist in the ClientDetails table i want the data to be moved to ClientNotExistindata

if the Client name from IMPORTClientDetails  exist then i want to move that into ClientAccountDetails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with two simple INSERT/SELECT statements.

```
INSERT INTO ClientAccountDetails(COLUMN1,COLUMN2, ETC)
SELECT COLUMN3,COLUMN4, ETC
FROM IMPORTClientDetails ICD
WHERE ICD.Client IN (SELECT Client FROM ClientDetails);

INSERT INTO ClientNotExistindata(COLUMN1,COLUMN2, ETC)
SELECT COLUMN3,COLUMN4, ETC
FROM IMPORTClientDetails ICD
WHERE ICD.Client NOT IN (SELECT Client FROM ClientDetails);
```

Comment: that doesnot work, because if i have 2 rows of data in ClientDetails and 20 rows in IMPORTClientDetails, then the data in ClientAccountDetails will be 40 rows whereas it should be 20 if name exists else less than that

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're describing.  Does it need to be only UNIQUE records? Perhaps you can make up some sample data and post it with the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer is what you want.  The IN() function will evaluate to True or False, so the row will only be inserted once.  I think you're getting confused with a Join.

Answer (score 1):

In SSIS you can use the Lookup Task to check if the imported ClientName rows from IMPORTClientDetails exist in ClientDetails - if there is no match, they can be sent to ClientNotExistindata.  The matching rows can then be sent to ClientAccountDetails.

Comment: I agree, since the data is being imported using SSIS you might as well make use of all the features available in it.